# Is there a way to disable nginx-ingress-controller default backend and use a static page for errors (4xx & 5xx)?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Let's say I want to disable the default backend of nginx-controller and just serve an static page for errors. Is that possible? I've tried mounting the page in the pod filesystem and add this to the nginx-controller configmap (using helm):

```
server-snippet: |
      error_page 404 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;
      location = /error.html {
       internal;
       root /var/www/default;
      }
```

But that does not work, even though I've managed to get the `error.html` file in `/var/www/defalut`. I would appreciate any comment that can point me out in the right direction.
The other workaround for this is building a custom Deafult Backend but that is overkill to just serve a static web page.

Comment: It seems like you might have a typo. You typed `server-snippet` and in [docs](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/configmap-and-annotations.md#snippets-and-custom-templates) I see there is **s** (plural) at the end of it (`server-snippets`). Is it a typo in your question? or maybe you copy-pasted it from config and you have a typo in your config

Comment: Strange. I have it without the s and it worked. I can see the snippets added to every host in nginx.conf.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I looked at the wrong config options. Anyway, I replicated this and it works for me. When the main pod gets deleted it defaults to error.html. Can you check file permissions for your *error.html* and make sure user `uid=33(www-data)` can read this file?

Comment: This works for SNI requests. It doesn't work for naked IP requests or browsers that don't support SNI, which will still go through to the default backend. I too would love to know how to disable the default backend.